# How to filter text in alert dialog box?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created a dialogbox which shows a list of countries ,i need to create the filter such that when i press a letter it should give all the items with the letter that i have typed.can you tell me way by which i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a auto complete, read up on how to build this right [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for that by implementing its methods like this:

```
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //... your logic
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // ... your logic
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // ... your logic
        }
    };
    et.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```